# FB login issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, authentication, comments

I am creating a [blog](http://www.nextunicorn.in). From the home page, if a user selects on any post, he/she is taken to the single post page. On this page there is an option to comment on that post, however, the user needs to log in to either Google or FB to post a comment. google login is working fine but FB login is giving error ‘You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.’.

I am using ‘super socializer’ plugin for this. The theme is ‘marinate’ just in case.

p.s. – I don’t have ‘https’ domain so can’t assign anything in fb ’s ‘Valid OAuth Redirect URIs’ field as it doesn’t allow ‘http’ domains.

Comment: Free option to utilize 'HTTPS'  https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Older existing apps will have about a year to make the change, but if you just created a new app id now, then your options are: 1) Get HTTPS. End of list.